# Need private personal access to ~three PHP pages

Tags: php, security, https

I would like secure access to the text output by three PHP scripts (the text output is JavaScript and html) . The security level is much less then financial data but important none-the-less.  I have considered purchasing AND studying https and SSL certificates. Hostgator charges an extra $2/month for a private ip plus $50+ anually for a certificate. This is more then I want to spend for this project (time + money).

Is there a simpler solution that is:

1. less expensive
2. easier to implement.

I'm open to different approaches.

Comment: Does the solution need to (a) secure data that is in transit, (b) be secure against other users on the same shared server, (c) work for a variety of requesters from varying IP addresses?

Comment: `secure access to the text output by three PHP scripts` --> SSL and a VPS (virtual private server) which usually means a personal IP address. I can help you get all of that for approximately 3 dollars monthly, plus a one-time SSL certificate (purchase one every few years). You don't need an SSL certificate to use encryption, though! You can create a self-signed one for free.

Comment: @danlefree a) I would prefer it was secure in transit, and b) it is hosted on hostgator, other users on server is not top priority, c) I (the only user) should be able to access from any IP address

Answer (score 3):

Given that you want the information to be secure (or as secure as is practical) in transit, you will want to encrypt the output of your PHP scripts using a password (or, preferably, a public key) stored on the server before returning the result and then decrypt the results locally with the password or private key.

A review of client-side libraries would suggest that [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/info/) could be used for this task with sufficient configuration, however, this variety of implementation is not documented at the jCryption site and implementation details would be more appropriate to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Just remember not to hard-code the private key or shared passcode in the client-side script. Instead, use HTML5's [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to load the encryption key from a file (which you could keep on a personal USB drive).

Comment: Don't roll out your own crypto with JavaScript, read [this](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/): in particular, you won't be able to trust the integrity of the script and the cryptographic operation (in particular random number generation) aren't good enough.

Comment: @Bruno Aren't good enough to *what*? Most people can expect to see their server or home machine as more likely exploit vectors than the JS crypto implementation on their website - and, where that's not the case, those to whom your statement applies already know who they are.

Comment: @danlefree, if you want to use some crypto, you might as well do it right. Sometimes, a false sense of security can actually be worse than no protection at all. Here, access from an IP address implies that it may be done from non-trusted networks.

Comment: I think we can agree that, if you want to *do it right*, you use SSL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a secure access to your server, it is very difficult to do it without SSL. You could try to encrypt your data, but if someone is eavesdropping, he can do exactly the same as the browser would do, to decrypt the data.

There are hosters with good solutions for this though. The hoster i am using myself, offers a *free* SSL connection with an URL of the form http://[mydomain].[hosterdomain].ch . For $50 yearly, you get a certificate for your own domain, this *without* the need for a private ip address.

Technically it's also possible to create a certificate yourself, there are two problems with this approach. First you have to find a provider that allows to install such a certificate, and second your browser will give a warning and the user will have to accept this certificate manually.

Comment: That's not true. SSL is just a convenient way to use public key encryption and authenticate hosts. There's nothing magical about SSL that makes it the only way to do encryption over the web. If you weren't concerned with portability and public access, you could potentially implement the same type of public key encryption yourself without SSL, or even just use symmetric encryption with a shared key exchanged through a secure channel as danlefree suggests (which is very practical in this particular scenario).

Comment: @Lèse majesté - What you write is true, it _is_ possible to do the encryption yourself. The problem is, that you have to install a software on the client side, before you can encrypt the data, while todays browser have built-in support for HTTPS/SSL. The software could even be a downloadable javascript, but then you face the problem, that an attacker can do the same steps as the client does. So, it is possible to do it on your own, but i can see only disadvantages. I will edit my answer anyway.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté, you should read this: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: @Bruno: I have read that, but realistically it doesn't really change anything for 2 reasons: 1.) the same MITM attack could be carried out at the point of browser download; so there's no guarantee that crypto code in the browser is secure, as many browsers (Firefox and IE at the very least) aren't downloaded over HTTPS, and I'd wager that less than 1% of users actually bother to verify a download using file checksums (and many who do probably use MD5 or SHA-1). 2.) Using JS/HTML stored on a thumbdrive + CORS circumvents the JS code security problem.

Comment: There are certainly many disadvantages to using JS for security, and in most cases TLS is preferable. However, the problem is overstated in that article, and there _are_ legitimate uses for JS crypto (even if you're already using TLS).

Comment: @Lèse majesté - I shouldn't have written it so absolute, but actually my answer was meant to be positive. There are hosters, which offer what Roger wants **for free**, so why not use it?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté (1) sure there's a point where you have to trust the browser and the CA certs it comes with, but that's completely different. You can't just say "let's not worry about MITM attacks when getting a webpage because I'm not sure about the browser code anyway". In addition, I got my IE through a genuine MS Win DVD (updates are also signed): unlikely a MITM would have tampered with it. (2) The JS/HTML on a thumbdrive doesn't solve the poor PRNG in browsers (use a full app instead). In-browser JS crypto might be better than nothing... as long as you're not expecting anything serious.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm not saying not to worry about MITM attacks. I'm saying that the level of attack sophistication talked about in the article would make the browser download an equally weak link, and that really the article is/should be arguing for end-to-end TLS/SSL for everything (from browser download onward). That's a legitimate position, but just realize that that's what you're arguing for. Also, the PRNG problem should be easily solved by incorporating mouse movement into the PRNG. Lastly, an example use case for JS crypto on top of TLS is something like LastPass.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté You can download/install your browser from a trusted network (or a trusted source) and use it from another. This is quite typical if you bring a laptop onto a Wifi network that's not under your control. While I agree you should be careful as to where you get your browser from, this is quite a different problem. Not sure the PRNG problem is that easy to fix either. Anyway, since the OP's host provides HTTPS (at least with shared host) on [all its shared hosting packages](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml), he should just use that instead of building something weaker in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Any custom code you write (or you) you do to display this output "securely" within the browser with SSL/TLS will be open to MITM attacks (see [JavaScript cryptography considered harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)): browsers don't give you any way to verify the authenticity of the code you're running (going through all the JavaScript code whenever you use it is quite unrealistic).

You get a few options:

- If you don't expect the output to be read from a browser, you can make your server encrypt the data, then you can save it from your browser and decipher that file using another application.
- Some shared hosting services will still serve your content at `https://www.yourserver.example/` using their own certificate (only valid for `www.yourhost.example`, but not `www.yourserver.example`).

  If this works in your case, and if you can trust that the certificate presented to you by the server is realistically that of the server on which your service is hosted (e.g. a cert that would be valid for `www.yourhost.example`), you can add a permanent security exception in Firefox (for example). This is usually not acceptable if your site is for more public use, but if you can judge that you can trust that server certificate, you will still have all the benefits of SSL/TLS when connecting to that server. This is clearly not ideal and require some of your own judgement when setting such exception. In your case, if the certificate you get for `https://www.yourserver.example/`is valid for `secure1.hostgator.com` (or something like that), it would seem reasonable to assume you're connecting to your shared server.
- Use your host's shared SSL facility (as [they seem to provide one](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-tools/ssl-certificates/how-to-set-up-and-use-your-shared-ssl)). The URL won't look like it's yours, but it should at least be secure without any specific exception, and it's fine for personal access.

**EDIT:** To clarify the point about custom code.

Most modern browsers have a key/cert container (e.g. Software Security device on Firefox at least) where private keys can be used for SSL/TLS client authentication.

In this case, the private key is always controlled by the browser itself, and never given away to any page or script. However, browsers generally don't expose the private key in the same way for use by JavaScript so as to be able to decrypt some content without giving full access to the private key itself: in this case, you could never be certain that the key isn't sent to some other server, especially in a context where a MITM attacker would have been in a position to alter the script (which is unverifiable, since you can't really see the code you're running on a page).

There is a [Mozilla JavaScript extension (`signText`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_crypto) that should protect the key for signing the correct way, but there's nothing to decrypt. There are also [on-going efforts to make more cryptographic operations available](http://domcrypt.org/), but this isn't ready at this stage (it's not clear whether it will be implemented in IE either).

Comment: -1 "Any custom code ... will be open to MITM attacks" - this is incorrect in the case of a public key copied to the server and used in combination with a private key, used for Javascript-based decryption, which is never transmitted to the server.

Comment: @ danelfree - The keypoint is, that you have to install something on each client manually, either a plugin, a certificate or a key. This maybe acceptable or not, that depends on the requirements of the user. It is _not_ safe, to load the encryption-code from the server, because you cannot make sure that you get the original untampered code, without using SSL.

Comment: @danlefree, you can't access the private key in your browser from JavaScript and use it for signing. You'd need to write a plugin to do that. If you were to use a private key from a script (e.g. by pasting it in a form), it would effectively be accessible from the script. In a MITM scenario, the script could be altered and the private key could leave your browser quite easily.

Comment: @Bruno If your server is merely spitting out ciphertext and you're running a local Javascript (sure, just save the key to a variable) to pull it down from the server and decrypt there is no MITM issue.

Comment: @danlefree, no, a MITM could alter your script so as to make it send your private key wherever he wants. You can't realistically be expected to check the whole script (and everything that runs on that page) via the developer tools or similar whenever you go to your page. That's one of the key problems with script-based crypto. Even [the jCryption author](http://www.jcryption.org/faq/) says it's vulnerable to MITM attacks (*How secure is jCryption?*)

Comment: I was talking about using jCryption's libraries, not the implementation described at the site. See above - "local Javascript"

Comment: @danlefree, so you mean running your script from a `file:///` URL? Doesn't that kill the flexibility of accessing the site from anywhere? You'd need to have that script with you at all times (and you'd run into cross-site issues if you want to pull the data directly). That would effectively be the same as running a separate application, no longer web-based (my bullet point #1).

Comment: @Bruno Implementation is tangential to the asker's question as I understand it ("Can it be done?") and there are other SE sites better-suited to the question of how to do it, as I stated in my answer.

Comment: @danlefree, I read this not just as "Can it be done?", but "Can it be done securely, using a normal/modern web-browser?" (incl. MITM threats). Sure, implementation is tangential: if the functions required to encrypt/decrypt properly within the browser (still protecting the private key), you could do something reasonable without SSL/TLS, but they're not... (Anyway, his host's shared SSL facility is certainly the best way to go here.)